# why i can´t install any version of netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Can't install netbeans due to this [NetbeansError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SieVZ.png)

I tried with netbeans 18, 17 and 8(all tried with JDK 18,17, and 8) and the error persists. Tried to find a fix on google but nothing helps

Here is the details(log) about this error:

```
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.375]: NameResolver - to parse &Help!
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.375]: NameResolver - to parse < &Back
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.375]: NameResolver - to parse &Next >
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.375]: NameResolver - to parse Cancel
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.375]: NameResolver - to parse I &accept the terms in the license agreement
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.375]: NameResolver - to parse org/netbeans/installer/product/components/netbeans-license.txt
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.379]: NameResolver - to parse $R{org/netbeans/installer/product/components/netbeans-license.txt;UTF-8}
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.395]: NameResolver - to parse {0}
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.535]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.535]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.555]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.555]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.555]: NameResolver - to parse Please read the following license agreement carefully.
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.673]: NameResolver - to parse License Agreement
[2023-07-28 11:01:00.673]: NameResolver - to parse Please read the following license agreement carefully.
[2023-07-28 11:01:30.987]: NameResolver - to parse C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2
[2023-07-28 11:01:30.991]: NameResolver - to parse 1.8.0.0.0
[2023-07-28 11:01:30.991]: NameResolver - to parse 500.0.0
[2023-07-28 11:01:30.991]: NameResolver - to parse .*
[2023-07-28 11:01:30.991]: NameResolver - to parse false
[2023-07-28 11:01:30.991]: NameResolver - to parse false
[2023-07-28 11:01:30.991]: NameResolver - to parse false
[2023-07-28 11:01:30.995]: NameResolver - to parse false
[2023-07-28 11:01:30.995]: ... use Java that is already selected for the product: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]: An unexpected exception happened in thread AWT-EventQueue-0
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeForceCollapse(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.get(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.addItem(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.access$800(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI.doDirectoryChanged(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI.access$1100(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI$11.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.utils.helper.swing.NbiFileChooser.<init>(NbiFileChooser.java:54)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.utils.helper.swing.NbiDirectoryChooser.<init>(NbiDirectoryChooser.java:51)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.components.panels.DestinationPanel$DestinationPanelSwingUi.initComponents(DestinationPanel.java:432)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.components.panels.DestinationPanel$DestinationPanelSwingUi.<init>(DestinationPanel.java:222)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.products.nb.base.wizard.panels.NbBasePanel$NbBaseDestinationPanelSwingUi.<init>(NbBasePanel.java:280)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.products.nb.base.wizard.panels.NbBasePanel$NbBaseDestinationPanelUi.getSwingUi(NbBasePanel.java:255)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.containers.SwingFrameContainer.updateWizardUi(SwingFrameContainer.java:228)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.Wizard.next(Wizard.java:609)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.components.sequences.ProductWizardSequence.executeForward(ProductWizardSequence.java:63)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.Wizard.next(Wizard.java:615)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.components.WizardPanel$WizardPanelSwingUi.evaluateNextButtonClick(WizardPanel.java:222)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.containers.SwingFrameContainer$8.actionPerformed(SwingFrameContainer.java:425)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.068]:  at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]: ... show message dialog
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.085]:     title: Critical Error
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.088]:     message: An unexpected exception happened in thread AWT-EventQueue-0
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.088]:     
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.088]:     Exception:
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.088]:       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.088]:       Comparison method violates its general contract!
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.088]:     
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.088]:     You can get more details about the issue in the installer log file:
[2023-07-28 11:01:31.088]:      C:\Users\crist\.nbi\log\20230728105427.log
```

Help me what i can do to fix it o any suggest for another IDE for Java web services development.

Log file here:
[logFile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZKt45EQPwWiLk3iK5XFfV-7xVSwJ_QK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Put `C:\Users\crist\.nbi\log\20230728105427.log` in the question please.

Comment: Have you checked your available disk space?

Comment: Yes, 55gb of free disk.

Comment: The free version of Intellij IDEA is very good.

Comment: @tgdavies works for web services and cxf ?

Comment: From your log you have at least two problems: [1] You are attempting to install NetBeans 8.2 using JDK 17, which is unsupported. Use JDK 8 with NetBeans 8.2. [2] Despite your claim that you have sufficient disk space, the message _"Insufficient disk space for extracting the installation data."_ is logged repeatedly. So recheck your disk space, and remove JDK 17 from your environment. Using JDK 17 also explains the error _"Comparison method violates its general contract!Comparison method violates its general contract!"_

Comment: That said, consider installing an IDE other than NetBeans 8.2. That release is very old and unsupported, and cannot work properly with any Java release > JDK 8. Is there any reason you _must_ use 8.2? If not, perhaps [install NetBeans 18 instead](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html), which will work fine with JDK 17. But if you follow that approach, also remove JDK 8 unless you need it for other reasons. Having multiple versions of Java on your machine is fine in principle,  but can result in unexpected problems sometimes.

Comment: @skomisa i removed all jdk and enviroments variables, restarted my laptop, now tried to install latest netbeans(18) whit jdk 17 , 18 and 20 having only one version of jdk installed per try, but nothing works, error is the same. I have more than 50GB of free disk space

Comment: @CristianArias Are you still getting that same _"Comparison method violates its general contract!"_ error when using JDK 17 with NetBeans 18? I don't see how that can occur if you don't have any other JDKs on your machine. Since you are on Windows double check your `PATH` variable to verify that only one JDK is referenced, and double check that there is only one JDK residing on your machine. Also open a Command Prompt window and submit **java -version** to verify that the version shown is what you expect. Otherwise, if you only have one JDK installed on your machine then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: That said, although it doesn't help to resolve your issue at all, I agree with the earlier comment that the [free ("community") version of Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) is very good, with [great tutorials](https://lp.jetbrains.com/academy/learn-java/). The learning curve is a bit higher than for NetBeans initially, but it is now far more popular than NetBeans.

Comment: @skomisa yep , there's no solution for now, i did all the checks for jdk , enviroment, versions installed , compatibilty , but nothing is working, for now i will work with community edition of netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

A customer started getting this same error in a different piece of software after their IT upgraded machines to Windows 11.
In our case, the software uses bundled 32-bit Java 1.8.0_192 and was working prior to Windows 11.

The stack trace includes

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeForceCollapse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.addItem(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI.doDirectoryChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI.access$1100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI$11.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

It looks to me like a problem between Windows 11 and Java.
Since you seem to be using 64-bit Java, the architecture of Java does not matter.

I could not reproduce this on an older version of Windows 11.

Are you also using Windows 11? If yes, perhaps you can try to roll back any recent updates?

Alternatively, here https://github.com/skylot/jadx/issues/1628#issuecomment-1211945290 xxr0ss suggests trying with

`-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true` in `JVM_OPTS`